# Wordpress Pagination not working in Plugin Admin

Tags: php, pagination, wordpress, admin

I have been trying various methods for the better part of the past three days, and I've crawled through innumerable replies here on StackOverflow and Wordpress support. Is it possible to have pagination in my plugin that lists posts for an administrator?

My plugin displays posts for an administrator so they can view certain details and add/edit specific options for each page. I realize this could be done using meta data on each individual page but I need to have it done this way: Load, let's say, 25 posts at a time, and allow the admin to add minor details about each one.

I've tried every variation (I say every but let's just say it's been every variation I can find on the top 20 pages or so of Google for all kinds of search phrases) using `previous_posts_links`, `paginate_links()`, etc; I've tried using custom `wp_query()` functions, instantiating a new wp_query and restoring it when I'm done (not recommended) and have avoided altogether using `query_posts()`. I've tried adding `pre_get_posts()` functions - but on that point while `get_posts()` might be faster than running a new `wp_query()`, apparently it's even more difficult to use with paginating it's results.

The code I've tried include all manner of variations of this idea:

```
<?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;             
    $my_query = new WP_Query( 
      array(
      'number' => -1,
      'posts_per_page' => '25',
      'paged' => $paged
    ) );

  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 
     echo "<div style='border:2px groove black; margin-bottom:5px;'><h3 class='postlist'>";
     the_title(); 
     echo "</h3></div>";
  endwhile; ?>

<nav>
    <?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Newer', $my_query->max_num_pages) ?>
    <?php next_posts_link('Older &raquo;', $my_query->max_num_pages) ?>
</nav>
```

(I've trimmed out the options saving stuff so it's easier to read). Noting this bit: `$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;` I've also tried it as 'page' rather than 'paged' and that doesn't have any effect.

This function displays what I need: the amount of posts I'm looking to load, and it seems to get the pagination correctly, and URLs for the pagination correct, but clicking on ANY pagination link generated *does nothing*.

I've tried Chris Coyier's fix regarding `$temp = wp_query... etc` and then restoring that but that doesn't work either.

Any ideas to get this working? Thank you so much in advance! I've been ripping my hair out for hours every day and getting almost nowhere.

EDIT: Also this example (below) pulled directly from the Codex, produces the numbered links, but *while they have the correct path/URL for pagination* don't actually progress to Page 2, Page 3, or so on.

```
$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $my_query->max_num_pages
) );
```

It gives me the links for 1, 2, 3 Next - but even thought the url appends `&page=2` the links don't work.

Comment: If you manually type in the pagination ?page=2 etc... does that work at all?

The issue with the pagination links may be due to using the "$my_query->max_num_pages" value - I would save this as a variable before you run your while loop and use that variable in your pagination code.

Comment: When I type `admin.php?page=my-plugin-posts&paged=2` it loads the **first** page (like it's been doing), but when I type `admin.php?page=my-plugin-posts&page=2` (note `page` rather than `paged`) it gives me a You Do Not Have Permission notice. I tried running `$mnp = $the_query->max_num_pages;` before the `while` loop and still nothing; I also tried running it before the loop directly after the query and still nothing. EDIT: Thank you, btw. :)

Comment: $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; may be your problem then - you could simply try... `$paged = isset($_GET['paged]) ? $_GET['paged] : 1;` your pagination links need to refer to paged then rather than page.

Comment: THAT WORKED! The pagination links are semi-functioning, however. In the list of `1, 2, 3 etc...` the link for `1` always stays no-link, `next page` always links to page 2, there is no `previous page` - but the links activating pages '2', '3' and so on DO work. It's possible I can try previous_post_link and next_post-link but then I'd have to go without individual paged numbers. I'l begin seeing what I can work out troubleshooting the pagination links themselves now. The big hurdle is getting it to advance. Thank you so much!

Comment: And the pagination has been fixed as well. This line: `'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),` had to be changed to this: `'current' => max( 1, $paged ),` and now it all works utterly fantastic. I can't thank you enough. This has been a three-day headache, very literally so.

Comment: Really pleased to hear that Derek :) glad to have been some help. I have added in an answer to this question - if you could accept that as the answer to your question that would be great, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

may be your problem then - you could simply try...

```
$paged = isset($_GET['paged']) ? $_GET['paged'] : 1;
```

your pagination links need to refer to paged then rather than page.